# jQuery validation - callback method only for fields that fail validation

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

Example: http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/custom-methods-demo.html.

The code:

```
validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
    },
    rules: {
        number: {
            required:true,
            minlength:3,
            maxlength:15,
            number:true 
        },
        secret: "buga",
        math: {
            equal: 11   
        }
    }
});
```

Question:

Is there a method that will ONLY fire if a field being validated actually fails to validate? `errorPlacement` above fires for every fields, regardless of validation result.

Thanks.

Comment: `errorPlacement` is a generic callback for all fields BUT it does not fire for all fields at once regardless of validation result.   It only fires for the current field being validated.  Please explain what you _really_ want to do as I'm afraid this question is just an example of the "XY Problem": http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/157574

Comment: And the "custom method" referred to in the documentation is not for callbacks, it's for custom rules.  There is no such thing as a _"custom callback"_ for this plugin.  You must use one of the provided callbacks and over-ride it with your own function… that's as close as you're going to get.

Comment: Is "XY Problem" a prescribed response when one does not understand the question?

Comment: Let's not be snarky, as clearly you failed to understand the rest of my initial comments.  The XY problem is when you're asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual root problem.  What is your initial goal?  What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: And the reason for downvote is the failure to describe it properly?

Comment: Ask the down-voter… but my guess is that it's a poorly constructed question.

Comment: ok, I thought it was you.

"Is there a method that will ONLY fire if a field being validated actually fails to validate? " - what can be clearer than that?

Comment: Hover over the down-vote arrow for a list of some common reasons.

Comment: Read my previous comments again.  Good luck to you.

Comment: ok, thanks. what's important is that the code below solves a problem, it might be useful and no one cares about the downvote.

Comment: What problem does it solve? Again, you asked,  _"Is there a method that will ONLY fire if a field being validated actually fails to validate?"_  When it seems like you really wanted to block the default error messages and replace them with something else.  <-  _that should have been the question._

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
$('#invite').validate({
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        if (validator.numberOfInvalids()) {
            for (i in validator.errorList) {
                error = validator.errorList[i];
                if (typeof error['element'] === 'object') {
                    fGrp = $(error['element']).closest('.form-group');
                    fGrp.toggleClass('has-error', true);
                    fGrp.find('.validationErrorMessage').html(error.message).toggleClass('nodisplay', false);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // Do nothing
    },
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: '/admin/isgmail/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $('#email').val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false
});
```

Comment: You really should put a `return false` inside of `errorPlacement`.

Comment: It's the best way to block the default error placement, rather than a totally empty function.

Comment: I thought _"Is there a method that will ONLY fire if a field being validated actually fails to validate?"_ was the clearly written question.

Comment: Since there's none, the code above addresses the problem.